# AWS cloudwatch alerting poll API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I can see that in AWS alerting works with SNS where protocols are available as Email, https and SMS...Basically push mechanisms..
Is it possible to make these alerts pull-based? any ideas around how this could be tried?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a solution for this, natively when an alert triggers it can be configured to go to either an SNS topic which has 1 or more subscriptions to notify.

Instead you would need to use the [describe-alarms](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudwatch/describe-alarms.html) function to retrieve a list of alarms, this can be narrowed down to alarming only by using the `--state-value` parameter such as the example below

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --state-value ALARM
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit your needs https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudwatch/describe-alarm-history.html ?

Please check `aws cloudwatch` there are several options for alarms.